# How to pass php switch case data through html form using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
action="cart.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>"
```

this is a form action where I'm trying to send data to php code where based on action switch cases are present here "code" is one of them.

I'm not able to figure out how to send a switch case data.

Comment: I'm not able to figure out what you meant. Please, provide more info.

Comment: in ajax how to send this data like $.ajax({
     url:'cart.php',
     method:'POST',...\

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, if you want to do it on submit.

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "cart.php",
  data: { action: "add", code: "<?php echo $product_array[$key]['code']; ?>" }
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Product Added: " + msg );
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i tried doing it... to check i put a alert inside the switch case 'add' it did not execute.